# WSH - List Available Functions

Tags: reflection, vbscript, wsh

I would be interested to know if there is any way for a script to obtain a list of available methods/functions within a Windows Script Host (VBScript) being hosted by some parent application?

If it was a .NET app, it would be using reflection, but I'm not sure if there is anything similar for WSH.

Comment: Hosted in what way? Using the [Script Control](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/184739)?

Comment: The scripting environment is BasicScript which i assumes was just a wsh wrapper. The product is fairly old, produced by a company called Summit (http://basicscript.summsoft.com/)

Comment: Looks like there is no way to achieve this. Nilpo gets it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Script Host is an environment.  It cannot be "hosted by some parent application".  Are you asking about using an alternative scripting engine?  You mention VBScript which requires one of the built in scripting engines, neither of which provide any methods of reflection.

Comment: As per comment above, the environment is BasicScript. I was looking to try and 'reflect' on the environment to obtain a list of all available methods/functions in the customised BasicScript environment. The 'parent app' being the process which created the wsh shell. Thinking about this now, if it is possible, wsh is not the way to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/vbscript_ref_functions.asp

Parsing .vbs file.

Or write vbscript Class and use IDL, DCOM analogy.

.Net? Use Powershell.